# Could not load file or assembly 'AspNet.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0'

Tags: asp.net-core, sandbox, cas

im using ASP.NET 5 MVC6, and i am getting this error whenever i try to run application:

> An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which
>   would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of
>   the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable
>   CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is
>   not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the
>   loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

and when i dive a little deeper in error i find this:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AspNet.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   Operation is not supported.

I tryed googling it, but no luck, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to run it from Visual Studio or IIS?

Comment: VS, wierd thing is that i had 1 day old backup of app, and when i run it everything works fine...and im not sure what i've changed to cause this error to rise.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue when deploying to Azure as well.  My only solution was to make sure the file and permissions on the folder wwwroot/bin are such that the server can see and access this directory.